# PCA9557 Port Zero No Output

Tags: digital-logic, i2c

I've got a really strange issue with some PCA9557 chips. I just had some boards manufactured by JLCPCB with [NXP PCA9557s](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/I-O-Expanders_NXP-Semicon-PCA9557PW-118_C141380.html) on them as IO expanders. I'm using a Teensy to drive them, and the PCA9557s drive some LEDs and MOSFETs (current is about 10mA per pin; the datasheet recommended value.)

For whatever reason, output 0 of all eight of my PCAs seems to be current-limited to half a milliamp. This essentailly drops to 0 volts when used to drive an LED; and rises to 5 with no load. Under a dead short, maximum drive current is only 0.5mA.

This looks like some sort of internal pull-up resistor being stuck on. However, I don't think that's the case - I checked the control registers by reading them back and they all read as appropriate; all seven other outputs work fine.

I have no idea what's causing this - I can't imagine all eight chips are simultaneously defective, but it's not impossible as they all came from the same lot.

Here's a screenshot of the schematic with the PCAs on it; take note of the "MISC IO" section, which is where I took the current measurements.

[image: Schematic]

I haven't brought out a scope to snoop the I2C lines yet, but the readback looks good.

Has anyone seen anything like this before? I'm at a loss after troubleshooting for a good amount of time. My best guess is that somehow there's some low-level I2C timing errors or the chips themselves are bad. I don't have any spares to solder on, unfortunately.

As for software information: I'm using a Teensy 4.1 with the Wire library.

Some relevant code snippets:

```
while(true) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            write_config_block(i, 0b1111'1111);
        }
        wdt.feed();
        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            INTERFACE.print(i);
            INTERFACE.print(": ");
            INTERFACE.println(read_config_block(i, 2));
        }
        delay(2000);
        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            write_config_block(i, 0);
        }
        wdt.feed();
        delay(10);
        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            INTERFACE.print(i);
            INTERFACE.print(": ");
            INTERFACE.println(read_config_block(i, PCA_CONF_REG));
        }
        delay(2000);
    }
```

```
void write_config_block(uint8_t address, uint8_t outputs) {
    address &= 7; // Ensure the address is less than 7.
    uint8_t i2c_address = (0b0011'0000 | (address) << 1) >> 1; // Form the I2C address of the device. N.B: The R/W bit is appended by the write() function already
    Wire1.beginTransmission(i2c_address);
    // Enable all pins as an output
    Wire1.write(PCA_CONF_REG);
    Wire1.write(0);
    Wire1.endTransmission();
    // Write the actual requested output
    Wire1.beginTransmission(i2c_address);
    Wire1.write(PCA_OUT_REG);
    Wire1.write(outputs);
    Wire1.endTransmission();

}

uint8_t read_config_block(uint8_t address, uint8_t target_reg) {
    address &= 7; // Ensure the address is less than 7.
    uint8_t i2c_address = (0b0011'0000 | (address) << 1) >> 1; // Form the I2C address of the device. N.B: The R/W bit is appended by the write() function already
    Wire1.beginTransmission(i2c_address);
    Wire1.write(target_reg);
    Wire1.endTransmission();
    Wire1.requestFrom(i2c_address, 1);
    uint8_t result = Wire1.read();
    Wire1.endTransmission();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You might have a code bug somewhere. In addition to the ones already present, as your design has only 8 chips but your for loop tries to  initialize extra chips from 0 to beyond 7.

Comment: Ah, good point. That was a change I made recently at what is likely 1AM local time. I think it's open drain on pin 1, and it's past 2am local, so I'm going to bed and I'll write up more tomorrow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The explanation is right at table "Pin Functions" in chapter 5:

> `P0` *[...]* P-port input/output. High impedance open-drain design structure. Connect to VCC through a pullup resistor.

This port pin can only drive to GND, not to VCC.

Comment: That's pretty crazy and random. Wonder what the purpose is. I'd expect every output to be identical.

Comment: It's also mentioned twice on first datasheet page, 3rd sentence on the first chapter and listed as feature/benefit on chapter 2. Chapter 5.2 says it's open-drain. And in chapter 6 there is a system diagram. And in electrical specs IO0 is again mentioned separately. The point seems to be that it is a true open-drain output with no FET or ESD protection diode to VDD.

Comment: @pipe As Justme mentions, sometimes you need such an output to drive loads from a voltage higher than VCC, see the example in figure 30 of the data sheet. But only sometimes. Or you want a wired AND. -- Anyway, this site is a QnA site, not a discussion forum. And one would discuss this with the manufacturer who designed the IC.

Comment: Common pitfall in many NXP chips. They love open drain outputs. It allows unpowered chips on open-drain busses (like I²C). The P-Channel high side mosfet would prevent this in push-pull conifguration - its body diode conducts to VCC.